# Why is Action.Execute returning 209: Invoke Validation Failed. User Forbidden to perform action?

Tags: botframework, adaptive-cards

I have a bot that responds to link unfurling with an Adaptive Card with some buttons that fire `Action.Execute`. When I click the button, the app displays "Something went wrong. Please try again", and in the Network tab I see "Invoke validation failed. User forbidden to perform action".

How do I allow the user to perform the action?

The `Action.Execute` works as expected in a private chat, but not in a team channel.

This is the relevant part of my app manifest:

```
"bots": [
    {
      "botId": REDACTED,
      "scopes": [
        "personal"
      ],
      "commandLists": [
        {
          "commands": [
            {
              "title": "login",
              "description": "login to account"
            },
            {
              "title": "logout",
              "description": "logout of account"
            }
          ],
          "scopes": [
            "personal"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "isNotificationOnly": false,
      "supportsCalling": false,
      "supportsVideo": false,
      "supportsFiles": false
    }
  ],
  "composeExtensions": [
    {
      "botId": REDACTED,
      "commands": [],
      "canUpdateConfiguration": false,
      "messageHandlers": [
        {
          "type": "link",
          "value": {
            "domains": [REDACTED],
            "supportsAnonymizedPayloads": true
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
```

the code to handle the button:

```
async onAdaptiveCardInvoke(context, invokeValue) {
    try {
    // The verb "userExecute" is sent from the Adaptive Card defined in adaptiveCards/learn.json
      if (invokeValue.action.verb === "userExecute") {
          const card = {
            "type": "AdaptiveCard",
            "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
            "version": "1.6",
            "body": [
                {
                    "type": "TextBlock",
                    "size": "Default",
                    "text": "Adaptive Card-based Loop component Successfully Execute!! ",
                    "style": "heading"
                },
                {
                    "type": "Image",
                    "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk/master/icon.png",
                    "height": "auto",
                    "size": "Medium",
                    "horizontalAlignment": "left",
                    "spacing": "None",
                    "width": "0px"
                }
            ]
        };
        return {
            statusCode: 200,
            type: "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
            value: card
        };
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('err: ', err);
      const error = new VError({ cause: err }, 'unable to catch invoke activity')
      throw error
    }
  }
```

My actions:

```
    {
      type: 'Action.Execute',
      title: 'Show Rich Preview',
      style: 'positive',
      verb: 'showRichPreviewSubmit',
      fallback: 'Action.Submit',
    },
    {
      type: 'Action.Execute',
      title: 'Dismiss',
      verb: 'showRichPreviewDismiss',
      fallback: 'Action.Submit',
    },
    {
      type: "Action.Execute",
      title: "Execute!",
      verb: "userExecute",
      fallback: "Action.Submit"
    },
  ]
```